# Pandas: Offset alias with hourly frequency on specific business days

Tags: pandas

I would like to create an offset alias that goes over every hour of my defined business days.
For example, I may have Saturday and Sunday as business days, and business times from 00:00 to 24:00.

`CustomBusinessHour` seems to be a logical candidate, however
`CustomBusinessHour(weekmask="Sat Sun", start="00:00", end="24:00")` and `CustomBusinessHour(weekmask="Sat Sun", start="00:00", end="00:00")` both are not allowed.
`CustomBusinessHour(weekmask="Sat Sun", start="00:00", end="23:59")` seems the next reasonable candidate.
However,

```py
freq = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessHour(weekmask="Sat Sun", start="00:00", end="23:59")
pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,1,15), freq=freq)
```

yields

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-04 00:00:00', '2020-01-04 01:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 02:00:00', '2020-01-04 03:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 04:00:00', '2020-01-04 05:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 06:00:00', '2020-01-04 07:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 08:00:00', '2020-01-04 09:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 10:00:00', '2020-01-04 11:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 12:00:00', '2020-01-04 13:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 14:00:00', '2020-01-04 15:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 16:00:00', '2020-01-04 17:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 18:00:00', '2020-01-04 19:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 20:00:00', '2020-01-04 21:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 22:00:00', '2020-01-04 23:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 00:01:00', '2020-01-05 01:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 02:01:00', '2020-01-05 03:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 04:01:00', '2020-01-05 05:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 06:01:00', '2020-01-05 07:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 08:01:00', '2020-01-05 09:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 10:01:00', '2020-01-05 11:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 12:01:00', '2020-01-05 13:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 14:01:00', '2020-01-05 15:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 16:01:00', '2020-01-05 17:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 18:01:00', '2020-01-05 19:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 20:01:00', '2020-01-05 21:01:00',
               '2020-01-05 22:01:00', '2020-01-05 23:01:00',
               '2020-01-11 00:02:00', '2020-01-11 01:02:00',
...
```

So, after each day one unwanted minute is added.

Finally, not specifying `start` and `stop` parameters of `CustomBusinessHours` will use 9:00-17:00.
How do I correctly create such an offset alias? Or is there some way to combine `Hour` offset with `CustomBusinessDay`?

Comment: Try end = "23:00"  if you're doing hourly, don't think you need the 59 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
freq = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessHour(weekmask="Sat Sun", start="00:00", end="23:00")
pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,1,15), freq=freq)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-04 00:00:00', '2020-01-04 01:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 02:00:00', '2020-01-04 03:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 04:00:00', '2020-01-04 05:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 06:00:00', '2020-01-04 07:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 08:00:00', '2020-01-04 09:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 10:00:00', '2020-01-04 11:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 12:00:00', '2020-01-04 13:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 14:00:00', '2020-01-04 15:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 16:00:00', '2020-01-04 17:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 18:00:00', '2020-01-04 19:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 20:00:00', '2020-01-04 21:00:00',
               '2020-01-04 22:00:00', '2020-01-05 00:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 01:00:00', '2020-01-05 02:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 03:00:00', '2020-01-05 04:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 05:00:00', '2020-01-05 06:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 07:00:00', '2020-01-05 08:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 09:00:00', '2020-01-05 10:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 11:00:00', '2020-01-05 12:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 13:00:00', '2020-01-05 14:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 15:00:00', '2020-01-05 16:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 17:00:00', '2020-01-05 18:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 19:00:00', '2020-01-05 20:00:00',
               '2020-01-05 21:00:00', '2020-01-05 22:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 00:00:00', '2020-01-11 01:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 02:00:00', '2020-01-11 03:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 04:00:00', '2020-01-11 05:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 06:00:00', '2020-01-11 07:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 08:00:00', '2020-01-11 09:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 10:00:00', '2020-01-11 11:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 12:00:00', '2020-01-11 13:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 14:00:00', '2020-01-11 15:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 16:00:00', '2020-01-11 17:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 18:00:00', '2020-01-11 19:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 20:00:00', '2020-01-11 21:00:00',
               '2020-01-11 22:00:00', '2020-01-12 00:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 01:00:00', '2020-01-12 02:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 03:00:00', '2020-01-12 04:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 05:00:00', '2020-01-12 06:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 07:00:00', '2020-01-12 08:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 09:00:00', '2020-01-12 10:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 11:00:00', '2020-01-12 12:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 13:00:00', '2020-01-12 14:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 15:00:00', '2020-01-12 16:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 17:00:00', '2020-01-12 18:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 19:00:00', '2020-01-12 20:00:00',
               '2020-01-12 21:00:00', '2020-01-12 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='CBH')
```

Comment: This approach is missing the 23:00 Timestamp on each day, however...

Comment: @Krasax I do believe you are correct, this appears to be a hole in the log, you can't define all 24 hours in a day with this method.

Comment: Submitted bug report: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49838